# offset in excel referencing the wrong cell?

Tags: excel, offset

I'm trying to use offset to link two sheets in a work book

I am in Sheet2

If I type `='Sheet1'!B6`                .... it gives me B6 from Sheet1

If I type `+OFFSET('Sheet1'!B6,0,ROW())`.... it gives me L6 from Sheet1

Why does it not pick up B6?

If I drag down the second formula it gives me M6,N6,O6,P6 etc, so it's at least consistent.

I've tried everything I can think of to get it to refer to the proper cell but to no avail. It's frustrating as I could have typed the data in by now!

Comment: Why are you offsetting the column by the row of the cell the formula is entered in?

Comment: Without the answer to @CoolBlue's question, we can't be sure what you need. If you want B6, why not reference B6 without the offset function?

Comment: What I'm trying to do is make items in row6 on sheet1 be dragged down in a column in Sheet2. 

Using =OFFSET(Sheet1!B6,0,0) give B6 but when dragged down repeats B6 ie doesn't progress it one column across.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
=OFFSET('Sheet1'!B6,0,0)
```

The "Row()" function is returning a value that is pushing the Offset 11 columns to the right.

Comment: This is equivalent to `='Sheet1'!B6`

Comment: @scott so it is. I should have provided more detail but it seems others have gone ahead and done that.

Answer (score 0):

To transpose columns to rows, try

```
=OFFSET('Sheet1'!$B$6,0,ROW()-1)
```

The second offset parameter is the row offset, the third is the column offset. Make sure to anchor the first parameter otherwise you'll double the offset when you copy down.

Comment: If I use =OFFSET('Sheet1'!$B$6,ROW()-row($B$6),0) this references B11 on sheet1 and when drags down just copies B23, B24 etc.

What I'm trying to do is make items in row6 on sheet1 be dragged down in a column in Sheet2.

Answer (score 0):

Your mistake is you have ROW() in place of column argument ? The 3rd argument in OFFSET is column number and not row number.

Try :

```
=OFFSET(Sheet1!B6,0,0)
```

In OFFSET, 0 Row and 0 column means it is the same co-ordinate as the current referenced cell. That is, from Sheet1!B6 increase/decrease 0 rows & 0 columns.

Answer (score 0):

I Have found a solution!!
If I create another column say B in Sheet2 and fill it with 1,2,3,4 etc.I can use the formula like this:-

=OFFSET('Outside funds'!$B$6,0,(B10-1))
It picks up everything correctly.
It may not be the best solution but it works.
Thanks for your help.